# Applying Delete Operations on Mirror/Parallel DB

Tags: database, oracle, postgresql

> THE SETUP

**Two Databases at different locations**

1. **Local Server(Oracle):** Used for in-house data entry and
   processing.
2. **Live Server(Postgres):** Used as the DB for a public website.

> THE SCENARIO

- Daily data insertion/updations/deletions are performed on the Local
  DB through out the day.
- Later after the end of the day the entire data of the current day is
  pushed to the Live DB Server using CSV files and Sql merge.
- This updates the Live DB server with the latest updations and new
  data inserted.

> THE PROBLEM

As the Live server is updated using running batch at the end of the day, the deletion operations do not get applied on the Live server.
Due to this unwanted data also remains at the Live Server causing discrepancy in the data on both servers.

How can the delete operation on local DB server be applied on Live Server along with the Updations and Insertions?

**P.S.** *The entire Live DB is to be restructured so any solution that requires breaking down and restructuring the DB server can also be looked into.*

Comment: It sounds like you need trigger-based logging of changes so those changes can be replayed onto the PostgreSQL server. There are a few products for that, including SymmetricDS, xDB, and others. It's not trivial to build one, use something off-the-shelf.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle GoldenGate supports replication from Oracle to PostgreSQL. It would certainly be faster and less error prone than your manual approach since it is all handled at a much lower level by the database.

If for some reason you don't want to do that then you are back to triggers tracking deletes in a table with the PK for the deleted records.

Or you could just switch out the PostgreSQL with Oracle :-)

Comment: Or you could switch out the Oracle, with PostgreSQL ;) !